# kafka streams stop working after upgrade to spring-kafka:2.5.3.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I am trying to upgrade my Spring-boot application to version 2.5.0

Once i do the upgrade:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.0'
}
```

I get an error saying

> Failed to introspect Class
> [org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.KafkaMetricsAutoConfiguration$KafkaStreamsMetricsConfiguration]

Checking this class i find that it is indeed broken as "addListener" in the code below cannot be resolved

```
static class KafkaStreamsMetricsConfiguration {

    @Bean
    StreamsBuilderFactoryBeanCustomizer kafkaStreamsMetrics(MeterRegistry meterRegistry) {
        return (factoryBean) -> factoryBean.addListener(new KafkaStreamsMicrometerListener(meterRegistry));
    }

}
```

The code above is coming from spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:2.5.0 jar.

This issue is solved if update my spring-kafka dependency to any version above 2.5.2.RELEASE

for example:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:2.5.3.RELEASE'
```

"addListener" is now taken from StreamsBuilderFactoryBean under the spring-kafka-2.5.3.release.jar

**The real issue** is that for some reason this change makes the Kafka stream bean not to run, and no consuming is being done. It seems to somehow break Spring activation of kafka-streams. There is no error of any kind or no indication that something went wrong. It feels disabled.

Some additional information:

i'm using

```
implementation 'org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams:2.5.0'
implementation 'org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:2.5.0'
```

changing their versions doesn't seem to have any effect.

Assuming nothing else changed (application classes and Kafka configuration) - what might be the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not specify versions; let Boot's dependency management manage the versions. The current Boot 2.5 version is 2.5.7; it requires spring-kafka 2.7.9 - see the project page for the dependency matrix.

https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka

[image]

Comment: where do you see spring-kafka 2.7.9?

Comment: Click the `Learn` tab on the project home page to see current versions.